# How should I convert a function returning a non-generic Task to ValueTask?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I'm working on some code which builds a buffer in memory and then empties it into a `TextWriter` when the buffer fills up. Most of the time, the character will go straight into the buffer (synchronously) but occasionally (once every 4kb) I need to call `TextWriter.WriteAsync`.

In [the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions) there only appears to be a [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-2.0) struct, and no non-generic `ValueTask` (without a type parameter). Why is there no `ValueTask`, and what should I do if I need to convert a method returning a non-generic `Task` (that is, the async equivalent of a `void` method) to `ValueTask`?

Comment: What behavior would you expect from a `ValueTask`? By definition a `ValueTask` can be used when the result is available synchronously. If there's no result what's the point or benefit over returning `Task`?

Comment: @JSteward I'm working on something which builds a buffer in memory and then empties it into a `TextWriter` when the buffer fills up. Most of the time, the character will go straight into the buffer (synchronously) but occasionally (once every 4kb) I need to call `TextWriter.WriteAsync`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd benefit from `ValueTask` but the docs suggest that _For uses other than consuming the result... ValueTask<TResult> can lead to a more convoluted programming model_. Maybe you could redesign your solution using something like [TPL-Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) that has numerous ways to buffer and process data.

Comment: @JSteward Thanks for the suggestion, and you weren't to know this, but Dataflow is massive overkill for my purposes, much as I love it. I want this code to be fast and not allocate, and I am willing to use a convoluted programming model to achieve that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but I think it's because [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) is sufficient for most non-generic cases.

One way to think of `ValueTask<T>` is as a union of `Task<T>` and `T` (for asynchronous and synchronous cases respectively). Accordingly a non-generic `ValueTask` would be a union of `Task` and... nothing, so just a `Task`.

I can't think of a case where a non-generic `ValueTask` would be practically different than caching an already completed `Task` (which is what `Task.CompletedTask` is), though I'd love to learn about any.

Comment: I don’t quite agree that a non-generic `ValueTask` would be exactly the same as “just a task”. More like `Optional<Task>` - the wrapped `Task` would be null in the case that the operation completed synchronously. You can see why this might be if you set `T` to some `struct NoReturnValue {}` in the formula `ValueTask<T> ~ T | Task<T>`. I _may_ be able to return `Task.CompletedTask` in my case, I’ll give it a go when I get home

Comment: It's not clear to me what the logical distinction between a `Task` where `IsCompleted == true` and a null value is (obviously, in practice the latter throws).  In both cases you know not to suspend execution, and the generated state machine will check `IsCompleted` before doing so.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this is going to work, thanks for the help Kevin. I was worried that an `async` method might always build a new `Task`, even if it completed synchronously, but from reading `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` it looks like that's not the case; an async `Task`-returning method returns a cached completed `Task` if it completed synchronously.

Comment: I do think it was a rather strange API design decision to not include a non-generic `ValueTask`. It's not at all obvious what you're supposed to do.

Comment: [Relevant new proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27445) that _would_ add a non-generic `ValueTask`.  It becomes necessary if you want to re-use the allocation required in the asynchronous case.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/), you can change any asynchronous method directly from `Task` to `ValueTask`, but you must beware of its usage patterns mentioned in the article; specifically:

- Awaiting the instance multiple times.
- Calling AsTask multiple times.
- Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.

And if you need to get the result back as a `Task` / `Task<TResult>`, you should use `.AsTask()`.