# Convert a ValueTask<T> to a non generic ValueTask

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, valuetask

The question asked here is the same as the [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935667/how-should-i-convert-a-function-returning-a-non-generic-task-to-valuetask) and is aimed to create a definitive solution to it.
The most accurate answer is by Stephen Toub himself in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31503#issuecomment-554415966) that is exactly about this question. The "recommendended code" is the following one:

```cs
public static ValueTask AsValueTask<T>(this ValueTask<T> valueTask)
{
    if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        valueTask.GetResult();
        return default;
    }

    return new ValueTask(valueTask.AsTask());
}
```

This answer is not up-to-date - a ValueTask doesn't expose a GetResult() (only a Result property) - and THE question is:

- Do we need to "pull" the Result out of the ValueTask (to "release" the IValueTaskSource that may operate under this ValueTask)?
- If yes:

  - is it the `.GetAwaiter()` call that is missing above?
  - OR is a fake call to the property is guaranteed to work `var fake = valueTask.Result;`? Always? (I'm afraid of dead code elimination.)
- If not, is a straight implementation like the following one enough (and optimal)?

```cs
public static ValueTask AsNonGenericValueTask<T>( in this ValueTask<T> valueTask )
{
    return valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully ? default : new ValueTask( valueTask.AsTask() );
}
```

Comment: Your original code is correct (just use `Result` i.s.o. `GetResult`). Adding a call to `GetWaiter` would merely result in an extra indirection: the result still only calls `Result` internally anyway without any added business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's missing in that code is `.GetAwaiter()`:

```
public static ValueTask AsValueTask<T>(this ValueTask<T> valueTask)
{
    if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return default;
    }

    return new ValueTask(valueTask.AsTask());
}
```

You're partially right in that you don't care about the result. But you might care about a thrown exception or cancellation that you'll miss if you don't query the result.

Or you can write it like this:

```
public static async ValueTask AsValueTask<T>(this ValueTask<T> valueTask)
    => await valueTask;
```

Comment: While the code segments mentioned are functionally similar, a trip though ILSPY shows very different implementations.  The top method generates far less code.  (At least in .net 5.0)

Comment: Of course it does. The second method generates a state machine and the first doesn't.

Comment: *"You might care about a thrown exception or cancellation that you'll miss if you don't query the result."* -- Not inside an `if` block that has passed the `IsCompletedSuccessfully` test!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ?

Comment: @PauloMorgado IsCompletedSuccessfully means the task wasn't cancelled or had failed with an exception. You may be conflating it with IsCompleted which is also true in cause of failures. But in that case the code would be wrong because it would throw before returning the ValueTask instead of returning a cancelled/faulted ValueTask (which I assume is what one would expect).

Also your alternative is problematic as it causes an allocation behind the scenes on current versions of Roslyn (it creates an instance of a compiler-generated class that implements IAsyncStateMachine)

Comment: Only in debug builds. On release builds it's a struct.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Oh, didn't realize that. Seems doing it that way is as good as any then.

Comment: The `GetAwaiter()` on a `ValueTask` is totally redundant here. It instantiates a `ValueTaskAwaiter` struct with the current vtask as value. Then, `GetResult` of that awaiter does nothing more than _literally calling `Result` on the original vtask_. Unless you want to use something like `UnsafeOnCompleted`, there is no use for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

```
valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

...or:

```
_ = valueTask.Result;
```

Both of those delegate to the underlying [`IValueTaskSource<T>.GetResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource-1.getresult) method, assuming that the `ValueTask<T>` is backed by a [`IValueTaskSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource-1). Using the shorter (second) approach should be slightly more efficient, since it involves one less method invocation.

You could also omit getting the result entirely. There is no requirement that a `ValueTask<T>` must be awaited at least once, or that its result must be retrieved at least once. It is entirely valid to be handed a `ValueTask<T>` and then forget about it. The [documented restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1#remarks) is:

> A `ValueTask<TResult>` instance may only be awaited once, [...]

It's a *"may only"*, not a *"must"*.

It is still a good idea to get the result though. By retrieving the result you are signaling that the `ValueTask<TResult>` has been consumed, and so the underlying `IValueTaskSource<T>` can be reused. Reusing `IValueTaskSource<T>` instances makes `ValueTask<T>`-based implementations more efficient, because they allocate memory less frequently. To get an idea, take a look at the internal [`System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation<TResult>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/AsyncOperation.cs) class. This class implements the `IValueTaskSource<TResult>` interface. Here is how the [`GetResult`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/AsyncOperation.cs#L130-L153) is implemented:

```
/// <summary>Gets the result of the operation.</summary>
/// <param name="token">The token that must match <see cref="_currentId"/>.</param>
public TResult GetResult(short token)
{
    if (_currentId != token)
    {
        ThrowIncorrectCurrentIdException();
    }

    if (!IsCompleted)
    {
        ThrowIncompleteOperationException();
    }

    ExceptionDispatchInfo? error = _error;
    TResult? result = _result;
    _currentId++;

    if (_pooled)
    {
        Volatile.Write(ref _continuation, s_availableSentinel); // only after fetching all needed data
    }

    error?.Throw();
    return result!;
}
```

Setting the private field `Action<object> _continuation` to the static readonly value `s_availableSentinel` allows the `AsyncOperation<TResult>` to be reused by a subsequent asynchronous operation (like the [`ChannelReader.ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync) for example). Otherwise the next asynchronous operation will allocate a new `AsyncOperation<TResult>` instance.

Comment: You are correct that these methods are interchangeable (in contrast to the orig. answer). One note on the `GetAwaiter`: this creates a struct of `ValueTaskAwaiter` with the sole value set to the current vtask. Calling `GetResult` on that simply calls `Result` on the vtask. This may or may not be erased by the CLR though, but either way, is redundant (unless you need another awaiter method).